# How to define a View-Model for header bar?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webstorm, aurelia

I want to create a View-Model for header bar. I use WebStorm + TypeScript + Aurelia. I have a `header-bar.html` file as you see in the following:

```
<template bindable="router">
  <require from="_controls/clock"></require>
  <require from="_controls/language-switcher"></require>
  <header class="header" role="banner">
    <div class="header-wrapper">
      <div class="header-back">
        <a href="##" onClick="history.back(); return false;">
          <img src="dist/images/01_back_32x32.png">
        </a>
      </div>

      <clock class="header-clock"></clock>

      <div class="header-signals">
        <img src="dist/images/01_Meldung_64x64.png" alt="Meldung" onclick="$('#notification-window, #cover').show()">
        <img src="dist/images/01_Wartung_Montage_kreis_64x64.png" alt="Wartung">
        <img src="dist/images/01_Aktoren_Kreis_64x64.png" alt="Aktoren">
        <img src="dist/images/01_Lock_64x64.png" alt="Lock">
        <img src="dist/images/01_Batterie_fixnav_64x64.png" alt="Batterie">

        <language-switcher class="language-switcher"></language-switcher>
      </div>

      <a href="#" class="header-logo">
        <img src="dist/images/fischerlogo300.png" alt="Logo Image">
      </a>

    </div>
  </header>

</template>
```

When I create a TypeScript file (View-Model) in the same directory and the same name (`header-bar.ts`) there is no relation between them. I can not bind the values between them. For example the following code (`header-bar.ts`):

```
export class HeaderBar {
  public telNumber: string;
  public hotLineNumber: string;
  public emailAddress: string;
  public constructor() {
    this.telNumber = "+49999999";
    this.hotLineNumber = "01726666";
    this.emailAddress = "service@xxx.de";
  }
}
```

Could you please tell me, how I can create a View-Model for this header bar?

Comment: Are you using `<require from="header-bar"></require>` or `<require from="header-bar.html"></require>` (ignoring any folder structure)?  I'm guessing you are using the second, with `.html` in the file name. When you add `.html`, Aurelia does not load the TypeScript or JavaScript VM, if you've written one.

Comment: @AshleyGrant I think the problem might be his bindable statement. He's declaring bindable properties in the html file, which only works for html-only components.

Comment: Nice catch. I missed that.

Comment: I use <require from="header-bar.html">. without html it does not work.

Comment: It should work without the .html once you added the view-model file alongside it. The file names have to match.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I deleted .html:

```
<require from="header-bar"></require>
```

But it was not enough for me. I changed the `header-bar.ts` as you see in the following:

```
import {autoinject} from "aurelia-dependency-injection";
import {Router} from "aurelia-router";
import {bindable} from "aurelia-templating";

@autoinject
export class HeaderBar {
  public key: string;

  @bindable
  public router: Router;

  constructor() {
    this.key = "one";
  }
}
```